# PHP Regular expression or str_replace and the string \201

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace, backslash, utf

I can't make this PHP to work:

```
$fo = "m\201 m\901";
echo str_replace('\\','*',$fo);
echo '<br>';
echo preg_replace('/\\\/', '%', $fo);
```

I get this:

```
m� m*901
m� m%901
```

As if, the `\201` is a symbol for some strange thing ?

Comment: That is the octal byte value notation, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double You can not replace a \ in `\201` here, because there _is_ no \ in the content of $fo in that place, after the PHP parser has interpreted that line of code. (`\901` stays as it is, because that is not a valid octal number to begin with.)

Answer (score 1):

Try single quotes

```
$fo = 'm\201 m\901';
```

Answer (score 0):

A backslash followed by 3 octal numbers [0-7] in double quotes is PHP notation for a specific character. Check out the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).
The character \201 or \x81 does not exist in the UTF-Code. We get a � when outputting. 
The 9 does not exist as an octal number, so \901 is not interpreted as a character.

In single quotes, no octal numbers are interpreted as characters. However, a backslash itself must be written as \\.

```
$fo = 'm\201 m\901';
$new = str_replace('\\','*',$fo);
var_dump($new);
//string(11) "m*201 m*901"
```